# How to run rtsp video into browser?

Tags: html, rtsp, mpeg-dash, rtsp-client

We are developing an application, where we required to load the rtsp video into the browser without using any poxy.

We tried to VLC Plugin but it only supports for the ie browser.

Comment: "Hello, I have something, and I have a problem to do things with this". We don't really know what is your problem. Please explain a little bit more. How are you doing to load this video with proxy, what error do you have when you do not use proxy ? What do you mean by "we tried with VLC plugin" ? (I'm not in this domain so maybe people will understand more than me, but it seems to need more details like code or problem description).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any browser which natively support RTSP streams at this time.

The usual approach is to use a proxy or a streaming server to covert the steams to something like HLS or DASH, but you say you can't do that.

There does exist a VLC browser plugin which certainly did support this (not tested it recently) but it does not include support for chrome which may rule it out if you are looking for cross browser support:

- https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin/